# Combine interfaces to generate a new type with a conjunction of their attributes

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

i have an object `Locale` that holds the localisations of my app.

```
export const Locale = {
    EN: "en",
    DE: "de",
    EL: "el",
    FR: "fr",
}

export const Locales = Object.values(Locale)
```

I have another object representing an API type ie `Trip`

```
export interface Trip {
    id: number,
    title:  string,
    description: string,
    featured: boolean,
}
```

Some of the fields of `Trip` are translatable (in that case title, description), meaning that in some cases, the API sends the localized fields with their locale.

For example:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title_el": "Greek Title",
  "title_de": "German title",
  "title_fr": "French Title",
  "title_en": "English Title,
  "description_en": "",
  "description_el": "",
  "description_de": "",
  "description_fr": "",
  "featured": true
}
```

What I am trying to do, is to somehow generate a new type `LocalizedTrip` that has the localizable fields plus all the non-localizable ones.

I tried to utilize Typescript’s 4.1 [Key Remaps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-rc/#key-remapping-mapped-types) without luck

I have created a codesandbox to get the party started:
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-frog-dr6de?file=/src/types.ts

```html
export const Locale = {
  EN: "en",
  DE: "de",
  EL: "el",
  FR: "fr",
}

export const Locales = Object.values(Locale)


type LocalizedType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as `[what here?]`]: () => T[K]
}

export interface Trip {
  id: number,
  title: string, //Maybe create another type for the localizable fields?
  description: string, 
  featured: boolean,
}


type LocalizedTrip = LocalizedType<Trip>

const test: LocalizedTrip = {

}

test.title_en
test.title_de
```

Comment: Can you embed everything in this question instead of a 3rd party site?

Comment: I have included the code from the sandbox in an embed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to be clear about which keys should become localized.  A default guess I have is those properties whose keys are not `symbol`s and whose values are assignable to `string`:

```
type LocalizableProps<T> = Exclude<{
    [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends string ? K : never }[keyof T]
    , symbol>;
```

which produces this for `Trip`:

```
type TripStringProps = LocalizableProps<Trip>
// type TripStringProps = "title" | "description"
```

If that doesn't capture your intent, you can change `LocalizableProps` to some other type function which does (or gets close enough).

---

It also helps to have the type corresponding to the union of the locale strings.  Right now `Locale`'s properties are seen as just `string`, which is too wide for our purposes. In order not to lose track of the specific [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) values in your `Locale` object, we should use something like a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
export const Locale = {
    EN: "en", 
    DE: "de",
    EL: "el",
    FR: "fr",
} as const;

type Locales = typeof Locale[keyof typeof Locale]
/* type Locales = "en" | "de" | "el" | "fr" */
```

Now if you change your `Locale` object the compiler should notice and adapt automatically.

---

Finally we can define `LocalizedType<T, K>` where `K` defaults to `LocalizableProps<T>` but you can override it if necessary:

```
type LocalizedType<T, K extends Exclude<keyof T, symbol> = LocalizableProps<T>> = {
    [P in keyof T as  (
        P extends K ? `${P}_${Locales}` : P
    )]: T[P]
}
```

This is a fairly straightforward key remapping: for each key `P` in `keyof T`, if `P` is one of the specified keys `K`, use the union `` `${P}_${Locales}` ``, which becomes a union (e.g., if `P` is `"x"`, then `${P}_{Locales}` will be `"x_en" | "x_de" | "x_el" | "x_fr"`.  Otherwise, leave it unchanged.

---

Let's test it out:

```
type LocalizedTrip = LocalizedType<Trip>

/* type LocalizedTrip = {
    id: number;
    title_en: string;
    title_de: string;
    title_el: string;
    title_fr: string;
    description_en: string;
    description_de: string;
    description_el: string;
    description_fr: string;
    featured: boolean;
} */
```

Looks good, and let's see what happens if we specify a different key:

```
type LocalizedTripJustTitle = LocalizedType<Trip, "title">
/* type LocalizedTripJustTitle = {
    id: number;
    title_en: string;
    title_de: string;
    title_el: string;
    title_fr: string;
    description: string;
    featured: boolean;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20201109#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wDIQQQwDbBwC8cA3gFBxVwCiAcgFxwBEwyzANFZdQCI1NmAE2CceVGhkHA8Y6nABiAJUEAzKGIC+cHKkQp0AbnLkYATzCEsuAnpLnLEVXGv5gAbQDWwM07gPgP1cCAF1yAHoAKn8LK2w3OxY2ZjgAHxYRFPTWWTSWdRTI8JMAl3i8AEsALxwAIwIABSgIMFQAHgAVAD5iWhAEPABXETaKeXcAaTgK5DhvX2cOkIBaAH4mDsmQuFAYNiE9dCgZgHM4VbgppmRgADdgKDhNLx8-JfE4LlQzAFtaiDwXWM5FAkFg02QeygqhwCEIHWOYDIHwqQmugz+Dw4HxgFRgBCYR1O2PkIlQCERuJQhJgx2QJxJ1FUwBwMEGUGAaLg-wBLOQ2M0JVicARFTAAGVaacmi1EsFqnVGs1Wp1EV0IuEYpYRYjJXSTjLWr1mLj8aI8sJgOTKRUUMwTELtfKqpyOrFOlwprt9noaP0hiN5m8vr9-oDes7FcBDe1uj0SGNqO4GhC5q9Fjo9HAABQfeQp73IA6Xc5wAAGABJSA1NAB9KvBK2aMtwJgND4AShCG2TYUFjriNmqrsREfKw6EbssqrF6oi0VKzpHYt6iaoqPRmKgxnkpoItbYNP1O+oe+AtZER9OJ6oZ4PeCv9Jv-jx+-Uj5OhjgHzJFLFVOQA9kA-Z9fxtFAL2AECfytP8wAA+9oNJWDwMA984CJJ8PmZVl2U5JgeQIHBkGMbQigHMohxdSdEQAKUGdAOlfQgSCXSd3VFMAuBNZjmHVKItUHfAJ04+jGOY1cUS5ZAMVqB5nzvQ8MKlLDd2YyCkNPdSZE0291PQzDPxg61-1tYDlOPbCWTZDkuUIvlSLgIogA)

Comment: Bonus question - if the localized type has nested types that they have to also be localized, how would you approach it? Let's say that the `Trip` has an array of `Boat` that it must also be localized at its localizable properties.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most readable type, but this works. Requires TS4.1.

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#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-QIg3GraHdOLXVI016Mp9vv8gVJg4QsTi8QSYESSdiwJbKSpoBFE1AKAq2Qymbh5AkydozndoAA6E22mhaNtjl2cIA)

Usage:

```
type LocalizedTrip = LocalizedType<Trip, "title" | "description">;
// type LocalizedTrip = {
//     title_en: string;
//     title_de: string;
//     title_el: string;
//     title_fr: string;
//     description_en: string;
//     description_de: string;
//     description_el: string;
//     description_fr: string;
//     id: number;
//     featured: boolean;
// }
```

Definition:

```
type LocalizedType<T, K> = {
  [LK in keyof typeof Locale as 0]: {
    [TK in Extract<keyof T, string>
      as (TK extends K ? `${TK}_${(typeof Locale)[LK]}` : TK)]: T[TK]
  }
}[0];
```

`0` is used as the outer key to combine the inner objects together. The `TK extends K ?` ternary makes sure only keys specified in `K` are localized.

---

Edit: Based on Jcalz's answer, we could get rid of the `0`:

```
type LocaleStr = (typeof Locale)[keyof typeof Locale];

type LocalizedType<T, K> = {
  [TK in Extract<keyof T, string>
    as (TK extends K ? `${TK}_${LocaleStr}` : TK)]: T[TK]
};
```